# Jquery string and ace editor value causes error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

I'm using ace editor to edit javascript scripts and I seem to get an error on loading the webpage when I try to add set the value of a variable to `"<script>" + jse.getValue() + "</script>";`
I have also tried adding `.toString()` at the end of the editor value
and `jse.value()`
edit: I also tried `"<script>" + jse.getSession().getValue() + "</script>";`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I have found that its the `<script>` tag causing the issue I renamed the tag to something else and it worked fine, however I am still confused as to how I can make this work? I'm basically setting the contents of an iframe `<body>` but need to keep the contents of `<body><script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in the future experiencing this problem I did manage to find a solution, the problem was I was trying to constantly set the contents of two elements, a parent and child.
My solution was to move the `<script>` tag from the `<body>` and place it into the `<head>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin https://ace.c9.io/ ? 
Maybe you can get the content of

With 
var jse = $('.ace_content').html();

Comment: Yeah im using that plugin, and that's not actually the issue if you see I added an update, basically I can't include the string "<script>" for some reason.
Thank you for your reply though.

Comment: it's not easy for me to see the problem because i can't see all of the code;